# State passed through context is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make my context work properly.
I've added it and it works as it should if I pass a string as a property to the state. However, I want to pass a prop as the state.

So this works:

```
export class DataProvider extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      continent: props.continent,
    };
    this.updateState = this.updateState.bind(this);
  }

  updateState() {
    this.setState({ continent: this.props.continent});
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props.continent);
    this.updateState();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <DataContext.Provider value={{ state: this.state }}>
        {this.props.children}
      </DataContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

But this does not work (results in undefined)

```
  this.state = {
      continent: this.props.continent,
    };
```

Results in "undefined" when I try to access it.

I get the prop from a component named "Africa", which does this:

```
const Africa = ({}) => {
  return (
    <div>
       <DataProvider continent={["Africa"]} /> 
........irrelevant code
```

It successfully passes to my DataProvider component.
But, as I stated, when I try to pass that as a property for my state, it results in "undefined".

```
class JumbotronPage extends Component {
  static contextType = DataContext;

  render() {
    console.log(this.context)
```

A(DataProvider), B(Africa), C(JumbotronPage)
I'm not sure if it's because A and B recognizes each other. 
B and C does not.

So whenever I access C from A, B gets re-rendered, resulting in giving C nothing as state. Does that make sense?

Please, forgive me for being very green and new to React. I hope I make some sense.

This is part of my App.js:

```
<Router>
        <div className="App">
          <MainNav />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={JumbotronPageHome} />
            <Route exact path="/Europe" component={Europe} />
            <Route exact path="/SouthAmerica" component={SouthAmerica} />
            <Route exact path="/NorthAmerica" component={NorthAmerica} />
            <Route exact path="/Africa" component={Africa} />
            <Route exact path="/Oceania" component={Oceania} />
            <Route exact path="/Asia" component={Asia} />
            <Route exact path="/Memories" component={Memories} />
            <Route exact path="/Login" component={Login} />
            <Route exact path="/Jumbotron">
              <DataProvider>
                <JumbotronPage />
              </DataProvider>
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/CreateNewMemories" component={renderForm} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
```

I created a gist, if someone has the time an patience to have a look at my abomination.

https://gist.github.com/kalleftw/e79412034eafd29a2e26b1af24149e67

Thanks

Edit:
Do I even need to set the state? The state that is passed through context should be set according to the receiving props.

Edit 2:
I THINK it's because, A(Context) receives props from C(Continent). However, when B(Jumbotron) gets rendered, it never gets the props from C.

See image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQRc9.jpg

Any idea if this might be the case?

Update:
Clarification:
So, if I access my component "Africa": https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwmhO.jpg I'd like to load every country from my database with the continent "Africa"

When I click "Africa", I want to see every country currently in the database associated with Africa: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vvnh.jpg

When I click a country, I want to display the information from the database in a jumbotron: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Khxrv.jpg

The data I'd like to view: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwhNa.jpg

Comment: Why are you trying to update the state again in DataProvider component through componentDidMount?

Comment: Mostly just trying stuff out. Been stuck at this problem for quite a while now. Thought that maybe there's something wrong with updating the state, but no.

Comment: Do you have React Developer Tools ? In that you can check for the `props` in `components`.

Comment: And also, what happens when a component is inserted into DOM for the first time it executes in following order: constructor() > render() > componentDidMount(). So, componentDidMount won't help you here in this case.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. :) The issue however, does not resolve by removing this and adding the state in some other way.

I'm pretty sure it just confirms the problem. You see, in component A, the state is there, however, as soon as I send it to component C, it's undefined. This happens ONLY if I update my state, using the props that I receive from component B. I think that I'm missing something important, but I cannot figure out what.

Comment: Can you add DataProvider component also in your gist?

Comment: It's there. It's just named "FetchContext.js". I've forgotten to rename it.

Comment: try value = {{...this.state}} instead of value={{ state: this.state }}

Comment: I did and the object is empty. :(

Comment: Where are you inserting Africa component in DOM? I mean in App Component where have you put? I can see DataProvider and JumbotronPage components but no Africa Component in App.

Comment: I must've edited it away somehow. I've edited in my gist aswell. It did not solve anything by putting it back, though.

Comment: In App.js: You should put `<Africa />` then in Africa.js 
`<DataProvider continent={["Africa"]} > 
 <JumbotronPage />
</DataProvider>`

Comment: That didn't seem to solve anything. Everything it did was spawning the JumbotronPage-component inside the Africa component. I've added some pictures to clarity my problem more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212696/discussion-between-abhinav-kushagra-and-jannemannen).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Migrated to hooks instead of class component. Should've done that in the first place. Learning is a pain. Thanks for the input.